# Clearing memory issue in C++

Tags: c++, memory

I have a C++ code that generates random 3D network structures. I work well and if I run it manually (from the Terminal), I get two different structures, as expected.

However, if I create a small loop to launch it 10 successive times, it produces 10 times the exact same structure, which is not normal. If I add a `sleep(1)` line at the end of the code, it works again, so I guess it as something to do with C++ releasing the memory (I am absolutely not an expect so I could be completely wrong).

The problem is that, by adding the `sleep(1)` command, it take much more time to run (10x more). This is of course not an issue for 10 runs, but the aim is to make 1000's of them.

**Is there a way to force C++ to release the memory at the end of the code?**

Comment: "I could be completely wrong". You are.

Comment: @user657267 Well, the whole code is 2000 lines long... I was wondering if it could be answered in a more general way...

Comment: @n.m. Thanks for the constructive comment :)

Comment: @Wiliam If you cannot be bothered to take the time to [strip your code down to a minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), don't expect other people to be able to magically debug your code.

Comment: Run your code under `valgrind` - that should take you straight to the bug(s).

Comment: Sorry about that. The error is at line 1763.

Comment: @user657267 turns out someone could answer my question without the code. thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ does not release memory automatically at all (except for code in destructors) so that is not the case.

But random numbers generators uses a system clock counter (I may be wrong here).
In a pascal language you should've call `randomize` procedure to init random generator with seed. Without doing so, random numbers generator produces the same results with each run, wich is very like your situation

In C++ there is `srand` function that is typycally inited by current time, like in example there http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand

I dont know how you init your rand generator, but if you doing so with a time with seconds resolution and your code is fast enough to do 10 loops in one second - this can be a case. It explans how 1 second delay fixes situation.

if thats the case, you can try a time function with bigger resolution. Also in c++11 stl, there is much powerfull random module (as in boost libraries, if you dont have c++11x). Documentation is here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/

Comment: You should only seed your random number generator once in your program, never in a loop.